# How do I calculate the running time for each line of a piece of code

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am somewhat familiar with Big O notation, however I came across an explanation of Big O notation that I cant quite get.

```
int foo(int n) {
  int p = 1;        -------------->c1        x 1
  int i = 1;         ------------->c1        x 1
  while (i < n) {     ------------>c2        x n
    int j = 1; ------------------->c1        x (n - 1)
       while (j < i) { ----------->c2        x ((1/2)n^2 - (3/2)n + 2)
         p = p * j; -------------->(c1 + c3) x ((1/2)n^2 - (3/2)n + 1)
         j = j + 1; -------------->(c1 + c4) x ((1/2)n^2 - (3/2)n + 1)
      }
    i = i + 1; ------------------->(c1 + c4) x (n - 1)
  }
  return p; ---------------------->c5        x 1        
}
```

(c1  +  1/2*c2 + 1/2*c3 + 1/2*c4)n^2 + (-c1 - 1/2*c2 - 3/2*c3 - 1/2*c4)n + (2*c1 + 2*c2 + c3 + c5)

I understand that this algo will turn out to be n^2 because of the nested loops and the  reduction of constants and low order terms in the resulting equation. However, what I do not understand is how the rhs of the "x" is derived for example ((1/2)n^2 - (3/2)n + 1). Any insights into this will be most appreciated, I really need to understand the core concepts of Big O notation. Thanks.

[Check here for animated explanation](http://www.csanimated.com/animation.php?t=Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are n-1 iterations of cycle while(i < n)

Innner cycle will be executed 0, 1, 2, 3,..n-2 times - this is arithmetic progression, and its sum is (n-2)(n-1)/2 = (1/2) n^2 - (3/2) n + 1

Comment: Why is the second while loop executed x ((1/2)n^2 - (3/2)n + 2) and its statements executed x ((1/2)n^2 - (3/2)n + 1).

Comment: second loop is executed (..+1) times, but its condition (while(j < i)) is checked one more time

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop is performed `n-1` times:

```
sum(1, i=1;n-1) = n-1.
```

The inner loop is performed `i-1` times for each `i`, altogether:

```
sum(i-1, i=1;n-1)
= sum(i, i=1;n-1) - sum(1, i=1;n-1)
= (n-1)*((n-1)+1)/2 - (n-1)
= (n-1)*n/2 - n+1
= (1/2)n^2-(3/2)n+1
```

Using the well-known Euler formula for sum of numbers from 1 to `n`: `sum(i, i=1;n) = n*(n+1)/2`